# How to Show Driving Directions on New Google Maps via URL Link

Tags: google-maps

I have a simple Google Maps link on my site that opens a new page and loads the driving directions from our location to customer's address.
The link is something like

```
https://maps.google.ca/maps?saddr=[our address]&daddr=[customer address]&dirflg=d
```

Where [our address] is replaced with our address and [customer address] is replaced by the customer address. The Google Maps is loaded properly with the directions drawn out on the map but is there a way to expand the "List all steps" for the default selected direction on page load?

I'm guessing Google Maps will automatically load the "best" route when the page is loaded but currently the user has to manually click on the "List all steps" to view the step by step directions. I want it so that when the user clicks the link on my site then it'll automatically load the map directions along with the step by step directions already opened. Is there some kind of special URL parameter that I can pass to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same solution - If you are able to format the link in the following way this works:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/[customer address]/[our address]/am=t/

It would be good to figure out how to submit it from a standard HTML form though.